# Post multiple records to rails, wrap_parameters behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a JSON API. If I post a single json record like this {"A":"1"} for example, rails with wrap_parameters enabled turns it into this: {"model" => {"A":"1"}}.

I want the user to be able to submit multiple records at once, for efficiency, so they don't have to have multiple requests. I would think the way to do this would be simply to wrap it in an array like this: [{"A":"1"},{"B":"2"}]. But then in rails I get it like this:

```
"_json"=>[{"A"=>"1"},{"B"=>"2"}]
"model"=>{}
```

Is there any way I could get rails to look at the array and interpret it correctly? Or should I just use _json?

Comment: If you mean just with its standard RESTful API, I think probably not. But if you're passing the array to a custom controller action, I would probably just do `JSON.parse(params["_json"])`.

Comment: If you structured the json as a pair of child items of something else, a has_many association would sort this out for you.